# cron job to run python script

Tags: python, docker

I followed the suggested solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598239/how-to-run-a-script-from-a-cron-file-inside-a-docker-container).
And came up with the following docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ADD write_time.py /
USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python cron && \
    chmod +x /write_time.py && \
    (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * cd / && /usr/bin/python /write_time.py >> test.out") | crontab -
```

the write_time.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.now()
time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(time)

with open("time.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(time+"\n")
```

After i build with the below command and run it -

```
docker build . -t se
docker run -it se
```

I exec into the contaier, to check if either test.out or test.txt is created at / but i do not see either.(have waited for more than 2 mins)

Anything i am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: Absent any `CMD`, the `docker run` command will run the default from the `ubuntu` base image, an interactive shell.  That shell is the _only_ thing the container runs – there are no other daemons of any kind, including a cron daemon.

Comment: I will recomend to use alpine base image from cron

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Docker CMD needs to be set to cron deamon.